# Logic/Code/Extension for adding products to wishlist along with product options

Tags: configurable-product, extensions, email, custom-options, wishlist

**Update:
Can anyone tell me if this has been enhanced by Magento in Enterprise 1.14.1.0 edition?**

I want to add the product with wishlist along with product options. And also share the product with a friend along with those options in email.

Can anyone suggest me code/logic/**Extension (Enterprise Edition)** for this.

Comment: But there are no proper accepted answers! And I have asked for the extension also!

Comment: did you tried all the solutions in that  ?

Comment: that's for programtically adding product to wishlist

Comment: So override the add to wislist action , add that functionality when there is custom option selected

Answer (score 0):

```
https://amasty.com/favorite-products.html
```

This extension resolves the purpose to some extend. When we add the product to wishlist at first choosing the option, option does gets saved.

But when we edit the wishlist and choose the option, it gets saved.